# How to update column value based on last inserted record in another table

Tags: sql-server

Need to update `AttentionStatus` / `UpdatedDate` for `PatientId` in table1 when a new record is inserted into table2, also have to move `AttentionStatus` (`CurrentStatus`) to `PreviousStatus`. Update value is based on the latest insert in tabel2.

Code:

```
create table Table1
(
    Id int, 
    PatientName varchar(200), 
    AttentionStatus varchar(20), 
    PreviousStatus varchar(20), 
    UpdatedDate datetime
)

create table Table2
(
    Id int identity(1,1), 
    PatientId int, 
    Attention varchar(20), 
    Date datetime
)

insert table1 select 101, 'Patient1', 'Yellow', 'Red', '2021-05-28 03:22:06.650'
insert table1 select 102, 'Patient2', 'Red', 'Yellow', '2021-05-26 14:29:52.620'

insert table2 select 1, 101, 'Yellow', '2021-05-28 03:22:06.650'
insert table2 select 2, 101, 'Red', '2021-05-28 03:14:56.010'
insert table2 select 3, 102, 'Red', '2021-05-26 14:29:52.620'
insert table2 select 4, 102, 'Yellow', '2021-05-25 10:27:37.107'
insert table2 select 5, 102, 'Green', '2021-05-24 06:13:18.430'

Id  PatientName AttentionStatus PreviousStatus  UpdatedDate
101 Patient1    Yellow          Red             2021-05-28 03:22:06.650
102 Patient2    Red             Yellow          2021-05-26 14:29:52.620
```

Input:

```
insert table2 select 102, 'Green', '2021-05-29 10:24:25.007'
```

Expected output:

```
Id    PatientName     AttentionStatus   PreviousStatus     UpdatedDate
101   Patient1        Yellow            Red                2021-05-28 03:22:06.650
102   Patient2        Green             Red                2021-05-29 10:24:25.007
```

This is my attempt at a query:

```
update table1 
set AttentionStatus = t2.attention, 
    previousstatus = t1.attentionstatus, 
    UpdatedDate = t2.date 
from table1 t1 
inner join 
    (select patientid, attention, date 
     from table2  
     group by patientid, attention 
     having date = max(Date)) t2 on t1.id = t2.PatientId
where t1.id = 102
```

Comment: please show your attempt query

Comment: I don't get it: if the `update table1` query is executed in the same batch then you should know which rows they are without the `having...`, and if it is executed in a trigger you should use the `inserted` table. So how are you running this `update`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the fields `AttentionStatus` and `PreviousStatus` (because of database normalization.

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4f1e793068eca3e08813664ed0077e6)

The code:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN AttentionStatus;
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN PreviousStatus;

CREATE VIEW vw_table1 AS (
   
   SELECT 
      Id,
      PatientName, 
      x.Attention as AttentionStatus,
      y.Attention as PreviousStatus,
      UpdatedDate
   FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT  PatientID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By PatientID ORDER By DATE DESC) as row,
         Attention
      FROM Table2
    ) x ON x.PatientID=table1.Id and x.row=1
   LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT PatientID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By PatientID ORDER By DATE DESC) as row,
         Attention
      FROM Table2
    ) y ON y.PatientId=table1.Id AND y.row=2
    
);
```

This creates a view with the results like:

| Id | PatientName | AttentionStatus | PreviousStatus | UpdatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Patient1 | Yellow | Red | 2021-05-28 03:22:06.650 |
| 102 | Patient2 | Green | Red | 2021-05-26 14:29:52.620 |

Comment: Those fields are required as the table is referenced in reports.